# how to use angular-material 5 checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material-5

I want to uncheck box and disable the button, Which only works when opened for the first time.

Here is my template:

```html
<form>
    <div class="container">
        <div *ngFor="let row of interpreterLists; index as i"
        class="row">
            <div>
                <mat-checkbox type="checkbox"
                [value]="row.id"
                name="{{row.name}}  {{ row.lastname }} ({{ row.work_inprogress }}/{{ row.work_success }})"
                (chang)="onChange()"
                [(ngModel)]="selectedInterpreter[i]"
                #shoes>
                    {{row.name}}
                    {{ row.lastname }}({{row.work_inprogress
                    }}/{{
                    row.work_success }})
                </mat-checkbox>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<button mat-raised-button class="btn btn-success md-warn"
(click)="assignJob(documentDetail.id)"
[disabled]="selectedInterpreter.length == 0">
    <i class="material-icons">check</i>&nbsp;<span class="mat-button-wrapper">สั่งงาน</span>
</button>
```

Here is my component

```
getInterpreters(department_id, doc_id) {
    let params = {
      department_id: department_id,
      doc_id: doc_id
    }
    this.userService.getInterpreters(params, 'Bearer ' + this.token).subscribe(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.interpreterLists = res;
        this.selectedInterpreter = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < this.interpreterLists.length; i++) {
          if (this.interpreterLists[i].readyexist === 'Yes') {

            this.selectedInterpreter.forEach(item => {
              item.checked = false;//change as per your requirement
            });
            this.selectedInterpreter.push(this.interpreterLists[i].id);
          }
        }
        console.log('dhduchd', this.selectedInterpreter);
      } else {
        this.selectedInterpreter.forEach(item => {
          item.disabled = true;//change as per your requirement
        });
        console.log('fail: ');
      }
    })
  }
```

This is the web page
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Once you unselect a checkbox, what is the value selectedInterpreter property is holding? I believe its length is greater than 0 even after unselection.

Comment: interpreterLists Keeping the value behind the interpreterLists. Yes, its length is greater than 0, although it is not selected. What should i do

Comment: checkbox material provides an output event called change. you can listen to the change event whenever the checkbox is selected as well as unselected. you need to add and remove values based on the emitter value